# scnViewGesture.Plugin.Droid for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I using scnViewGesture.Plugin for xamarin forms. LongTap is working as expected in iOS, but in the Android the LongTap event is not working. please share your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a plugin to do this? Just handle the touch event, start a timer on the down event, clear the timer on the up event, and whenever a specified amount of time has passed on the timer, do whatever you wanted to do with the long touch on a separate thread.

For the record, I can't give you a better example because you've provided no code, and your question is extremely broad because of that.